# Replicating the Stata marginlist argument using R margins package?

Tags: r, stata, prediction, marginal-effects

I am unable to replicate in R a particular use case of the Stata `margins` command:
  `margins var1, over(var2)`
I've been trying to do so using the `margins` package in R.

To provide a reproducible example, I used the mtcars dataset and exported it from R into Stata so we are using the same dataset in both programs:

R code:

```
library(foreign)
library(margins)
write.dta(mtcars, “mtcars.dta")
```

Stata code:

```
use "mtcars.dta", clear
```

**Create an example linear regression model in both programs**

Stata code:

```
quietly regress mpg cyl i.am c.wt##c.hp
```

R code:

```
x <- lm(mpg ~ cyl + factor(am) + hp * wt, data = mtcars)
```

The model output (not shown) is identical between the two programs

**Compare the average marginal effects table for each variable in the model**

Stata code and output:

```
margins, dydx(*)

Average marginal effects                          Number of obs   =         32
Model VCE: OLS

Expression   : Linear prediction, predict() dy/dx w.r.t. : cyl 1.am wt hp

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |            Delta-method
             |      dy/dx   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
         cyl |  -.3708001   .5293674    -0.70   0.490     -1.45893    .7173301
        1.am |  -.0709546   1.374981    -0.05   0.959    -2.897268    2.755359
          wt |  -3.868994   .9170145    -4.22   0.000    -5.753944   -1.984043
          hp |  -.0249882   .0120345    -2.08   0.048    -.0497254    -.000251
------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
Note: dy/dx for factor levels is the discrete change from the base level.
```

R code and output:

```
xmarg <- margins(x)
summary(xmarg)

factor     AME     SE       z      p   lower   upper
    am1 -0.0710 1.3750 -0.0516 0.9588 -2.7659  2.6240
    cyl -0.3708 0.5294 -0.7005 0.4836 -1.4083  0.6667
     hp -0.0250 0.0120 -2.0764 0.0379 -0.0486 -0.0014
     wt -3.8690 0.9170 -4.2191 0.0000 -5.6663 -2.0717
```

As you can see, these two outputs are very similar to one another, as expected using the R `margins` package.

**Problem 1: Marginal predictions OVER the value of a variable**

Stata Code and Output:

```
margins, over(cyl)

Predictive margins                                Number of obs   =         32
Model VCE: OLS

Expression   : Linear prediction, predict()
over         : cyl

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |            Delta-method
             |     Margin   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
         cyl |
          4  |   26.56699   .6390379    41.57   0.000     25.25342    27.88055
          6  |   20.04662   .5797511    34.58   0.000     18.85492    21.23831
          8  |   15.02406   .5718886    26.27   0.000     13.84853    16.19959
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

R Code and Output:

```
aggregate(fitted~cyl, data = xmarg, FUN = mean)
  cyl   fitted
1   4 26.56699
2   6 20.04662
3   8 15.02406
```

In the two examples above, the marginal prediction is identical between R and Stata. However, is there a way (short of doing it by hand) to generate the delta-method standard error for each marginal prediction as is done in the Stata table above?

**Problem 2: Marginal predictions for a specific variable:**

Stata Code and Output:

```
margins am

Predictive margins                                Number of obs   =         32
Model VCE    : OLS

Expression   : Linear prediction, predict()

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |            Delta-method
             |     Margin   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
          am |
          0  |   20.11945   .6819407    29.50   0.000      18.7177     21.5212
          1  |    20.0485   .9052764    22.15   0.000     18.18767    21.90932
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

R Code and Output:

```
aggregate(fitted~am, data = xmarg, FUN = mean)
  am   fitted
1  0 17.14737
2  1 24.39231
```

In this example, we are trying to replicate Stata’s “marginlist” argument in the `margins` command by subsetting the dataset after prediction. This does not seem to be the right way. How can we replicate these results from Stata?

**Problem 3: Marginal prediction of one variable over the value of another**

Replicating this result is my main goal!

Stata Code and output

```
margins am, over(cyl)

Predictive margins                                Number of obs   =         32
Model VCE    : OLS

Expression   : Linear prediction, predict()
over         : cyl

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |            Delta-method
             |     Margin   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
      cyl#am |
        4 0  |   26.61859   1.246074    21.36   0.000     24.05725    29.17993
        4 1  |   26.54763   .7034599    37.74   0.000     25.10165    27.99362
        6 0  |   20.07703   .6449805    31.13   0.000     18.75125     21.4028
        6 1  |   20.00607   1.144518    17.48   0.000     17.65348    22.35866
        8 0  |    15.0342   .6228319    24.14   0.000     13.75395    16.31445
        8 1  |   14.96324   1.257922    11.90   0.000     12.37754    17.54894
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

R Code and Output:

```
aggregate(fitted ~ am + cyl, data = xmarg, FUN = mean)
  am cyl   fitted
1  0   4 22.83306
2  1   4 27.96721
3  0   6 19.06359
4  1   6 21.35732
5  0   8 15.08720
6  1   8 14.64519
```

As you can see, the point estimates are now substantially different and again there is no SE table. Solving Problem 1 and Problem 2 above will likely allow the solution to Problem 3.

Answer (score 3):

For these problems you want the **prediction** package, which is part of **margins**. It's not currently possible to get standard errors for average predictions, but you can at least get average predictions identical to Stata using the following.

The key intuition about Stata's `margins` command is the following:

```
margins x1
```

is equivalent to

```
margins, at(x1 = (...))
```

where `...` is all possible values of `x1`. Either of these expressions produces *counterfactual* datasets where `x1` is fixed at a given value for all cases in the data, and then the model prediction is performed on this temporary, counterfactual version of the dataset.

The `over()` option is a subsetting procedure:

```
margins, over(x1)
```

splits the data based the value of `x1` and then performs model prediction on each subset. You can combine this with `at` but it gets a bit odd to think about. For example:

```
margins, over(x1) at(x2 = (1 2))
```

fixes `x2` to 1 for all observations, then splits the data by `x1`, then generates predictions for each subset, and averages them. Then it repeats this for a counterfactual version where `x2` is set to 2 for all observations.

In R, `prediction::prediction()` will give you equivalents of the `at()` using the `at` argument. And it will also give you equivalents of `over()` by passing subsets of data to the `data` argument.

So, for your **Problem 2**:

```
> prediction::prediction(x, at = list(am = c(0,1)))
Average predictions for 32 observations:
 at(am) value
      0 20.12
      1 20.05
```

And for your **Problem 3**:

```
> prediction::prediction(x, at = list(am = c(0,1)), data = subset(mtcars, cyl == 4))
Average predictions for 11 observations:
 at(am) value
      0 26.62
      1 26.55
> prediction::prediction(x, at = list(am = c(0,1)), data = subset(mtcars, cyl == 6))
Average predictions for 7 observations:
 at(am) value
      0 20.08
      1 20.01
> prediction::prediction(x, at = list(am = c(0,1)), data = subset(mtcars, cyl == 8))
Average predictions for 14 observations:
 at(am) value
      0 15.03
      1 14.96
```

In neither of these cases can you replicate Stata's output by just doing a `predict(x)` and aggregating the predictions because the predictions are occurring on counterfactual datasets.

And, again, variances are not currently implemented (as of August 2018).

Comment: Thanks for this thorough reply! Appreciate the help

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and have found the following workaround. The thread is of course an old one. But I thought my solution would be easier to find when added to this thread.

I have simulated data of a dependent variable `dv` that is explained by variables `level` and `treat`, as well as their interaction.

1. Simulation of data

   ```
   N <- 1000
   uid <- rep(1:N)
   treat <- rep(1:10, each = N/10)
   level <- rep(1:100, each = N/100)
   err <- rnorm(N, 0, 1)
   hdv <- 40 + 2 * treat + .25 * level - .05 * treat * level + err
   dv <- ifelse(hdv > 47, 1, 0)
   dat <- data.frame(dv = dv, treat = treat, level = level, hdv = hdv)
   ```
2. Estimation

   As the dependent variable is binary, I estimate a Logit model. As is well understood, interaction terms in Logit (as in any non-linear model) cannot be directly interpreted.

   This is why I want marginal effects of "level" over "treat":

   ```
   logit <- glm(dv ~ treat*level, family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = dat)
   ```
3. Marginal Effects

   R can actually recover marginal effects with confidence intervals when subsetting the data, as in:

   ```
   hmpr7 <- summary(margins(logit, variables = "level", data = dat[dat$treat == 7,]))
   ```

   The following is a (somewhat involved) way of doing this for *all* treatments:

   ```
   hmpr <- list()
   for (i in 1:10) {
     hmpr[[i]] <- summary(margins(logit, variables = "level", data = dat[dat$treat == i,]))
   }
   # the result is a list. For further use it is transformed into a data.frame
   mpr <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(hmpr), nrow=length(hmpr), byrow=T))
   # in this process, all variables are classified as factors. This is changed here
   mpr <- data.frame(lapply(mpr, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x))))
   # only the variables of interest for the graph are kept
   mpr <- mpr[,c(2, 6, 7)]
   # meaningful names are assigned to the variables
   mpr <- setNames(mpr, c("pred", "lower", "upper")) 
   # treatment classifier is added to rows
   mpr$treat <- rep(1:10)
   ```
4. Plotting the result (as in Stata's `marginsplot`)

   ```
   plot(mpr$pred ~ mpr$treat,
   ylim = range(c(mpr$lower, mpr$upper)),
   pch = 19, xlab = "treatment", ylab = "marginal effect + 95% CI",
   main = "marginal effect of level per treatment")

   arrows(mpr$treat, mpr$lower,
     mpr$treat, mpr$upper,
     length = .05, angle = 90, code = 3)

   abline(h = 0, col = "red")
   ```